# Implement IDisposable.Dispose to release threads on wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, idisposable

My windows service is using .Net managed objects like Sockets, Threads, Monitors, Semaphores. I have two questions related to these objects.

1. Do we have to implement IDisposable.Dispose on classes using above managed objects, to release them in order to assist when the service stops.
2. We also have threads waiting on monitors. If we don't stop/exit them before exiting does the Garbage collector clean them?

Answer (score 0):

When you use IDisposables, you should dispose them somewhere. If they are references in fields, you usually need to implement IDisposable in that class and dispose it there. Threads should be stopped (using e.g. a reset event) and joined.

Comment: My question is if I am using threads and monitors.wait as fields do I have to write disposable on those classes just to clean them up before service stops.